# Генерация изображения на основе html+css текста PHP

Tags: php, html, css, изображения, composer

У меня есть переменная с текстом html+css. Нужно написать скрипт на php, который позволит сгенерировать из этой переменной изображение .jpg и встроить в проект, так как генерировать придется большое число изображений. Какую библиотеку php посоветуете использовать? Все те, которые нахожу, при установке не используют композер, либо не используют html или css, и я затрудняюсь в поиске.

Answer (score 0):

Из известных мне:

- GD
- ImageMagick

Кроме того, рекомендую присмотреться к генерации SVG